# spring-authorization-server and OpenId Connect and angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: spring-security

In my project i have an angular app where i use https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc and a SpringBoot backend.
In the UI i copied most of the Stuff from here https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards.

My Code works with https://demo.identityserver.io and with a local Keycloak.

I only have to change the only:

- spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri (in the Backend)
- In the frontend "issuer: 'http://localhost:8080/realms/master',"
  to fit to the corresponding server

My "Dream" would be to use the spring-authorization-server. In my app i can create User dynamicly, and there for i need to be able to add this user to the authorization-server with a REST call. As fare as i understand, the spring-authorization-server code that should be ease to extend.

I copied over the spring-authorization-server code from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server with the base spring-authorization-server version: 0.2.0.
The Server starts and my App does the Redirect to the LoginPage. When it comes back from the spring-authorization-server the angular UI OIDC code detect a problem with the "Nonce", sometimes is missing, sometimes it does not match. Unfortunately i was not able to find the reason for that behaviour :-(
As my code works with the other two implementations, i suspect either a misconfiguration or a bug in the spring-authorization-server.

The documentation on spring-authorization-server is pretty slim.

Question: Does somebody know a place where a spring-authorization-server is used with a web client an OpenId Connect?

2.3.2022 Update: I open a Issue at the spring-authorization-server https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/640
I hope this will bring some more info.

Best Regards T

Comment: The [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/499) from the official Spring Authorization Server repository is a good starting point. It uses a Spring client but once you have that working you can replace the client with your Angular application. Also check out [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297) for best practices when using the Spring Authorization Seriver with SPAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave up on angular-oauth2-oidc after days of suffering. With angular-auth-oidc-client it works after 2h :-) They have better documentation and way more examples with different scenarios. I really can recommend it :-)

@Steve Thanks for the hint with the lib angular-auth-oidc-client.

Comment: especially if you want to lazy-load the configs angular-auth-oidc-client is the better choice

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with angular-oauth2-oidc. However, I would recommend [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client).

See [this branch](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/tree/backend-for-frontend/samples/angular-client) containing a working sample that uses this client. The sample demonstrates obtaining an access token as a public client as well as authenticating to a backend for frontend application (or BFF, which is the recommended choice) without using any client-side library. We will be presenting a webinar on March 10, 2022 on this topic. You can register [here](https://www.brighttalk.com/webcast/14893/528772).

You can also check out [this sample](https://github.com/sjohnr/springone-2021/) from SpringOne 2021, which also demonstrates an Angular application utilizing a BFF and retrieving data from a resource server.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with angular-auth-oidc-client, i have seen it. I choose angular-oauth2-oidc because it has 4x more weekly download and Manfred Steyer is a known speaker on Angular conference. As both libs are certified, i think/hope it should not make much difference.

Comment: I would hope so too. However, I have not had any issues and have a working sample. So if that helps you configure angular-oauth2-oidc, cool. Otherwise, I mentioned it in case it's worth a try.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of both your SPA and the authorization server configuration?

Comment: Yes i will. This should be quite easy. I take the two example and adjust them a bit. You will here from me.