# Springboot JWT Invalid Signature using Auth0 via OIDC

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, openid-connect, auth0, signature

I am trying to learning spring security and created a sample project where an angular based UI is authenticated using OIDC with PKCE through springboot. I am authenticating users with Auth0 following this tutorial https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/guides/how-to-social-login.html from spring.  I am able to login correctly, but the access and id tokens that is generated always fail the signature validation.  Is there anything I am missing in my configure files that may cause the signature to not fail?

application.yaml

```
server:
  port: 9000
auth:
    client: <insert auth0 address here>
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${auth.client}
          jwk-set-uri: ${auth.client}/.well-known/jwks.json
      client:
        registration:
          my-client:
            provider: test
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/my-client
            client-authentication-method: none
            client-id: xxxx
            client-secret: yyyyyy
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email
              - read.data
        provider:
          test:
            issuer-uri: ${auth.client}/
            authorization-uri: ${auth.client}/authorize
            token-uri: ${auth.client}/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: ${auth.client}/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: ${auth.client}/.well-known/jwks.json
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          - my-client:
            registration:
              client-id: "public-client"
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "none"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "authorization_code"
              redirect-uris:
                - "http://localhost:4200"
              scopes:
                - "openid"
                - "profile"
                - "offline_access"
            require-authorization-consent: true
            require-proof-key: true
            token:
                access-token-time-to-live: 600s
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        
                http
            // Redirect to the OAuth 2.0 Login endpoint when not authenticated
            // from the authorization endpoint
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor( 
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/my-client"),
                    new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                )
            )
            // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
                        .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults()); 
        return http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:4200");
                config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
              
}
```

Here is an example access token

```
eyJraWQiOiJmOGI2OWFmNi1jYmE1LTQ1YzAtOGY4NC1kNWMzMDI3ZjQzZDUiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw2MjA1YzJjYzY5NDVmOTAwNmI1Yzg1YWMiLCJhdWQiOiJwdWJsaWMtY2xpZW50IiwibmJmIjoxNzA1MTU3ODIwLCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJwcm9maWxlIiwib2ZmbGluZV9hY2Nlc3MiXSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5MDAwIiwiZXhwIjoxNzA1MTU4NDIwLCJpYXQiOjE3MDUxNTc4MjAsImp0aSI6ImNjMzRlZTRkLTNmYzQtNGRiZi05YTI2LTBlNmNiNjg5YzMwZiJ9.TUNQLWUYnKjn8XCfyQRtkDLXbt4PBKheP9u60t8by_5C6318NRUkfxJlAh2ye5Gv2ZMWQDjXbTOznB0W5IsMA8x67oq49QRpmHYW_Gd23968DGo00XHAt4GEQaR7COh-Tm7yRwp3ihIwGPWDffYT0bTUrCwzEH8OpYu26CSXzyTa7Cc7VcuTnf1qlRysI2j-jwyIkTM-V8JppffIcuTz-r0dRbxsi4tYGNEvmRghY-QNuApc_BekVr0pOq9rMblaUOMz2zOcoCN0O1ty1XXb-6hLWUemOO3Q7Zdj4N-s6cx42EbFv6L_fsj7oYCYq-Pzt-hzLCDRQfTpYf4-TD9ccw
```

Here is the results from the local host jwk endpoint

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "e": "AQAB",
            "kid": "f8b69af6-cba5-45c0-8f84-d5c3027f43d5",
            "n": "s6z7mFu60eiD5zAgpiz6rL2ZsdayRf5xM95BHloWD_xz9n56l6oBX82gXpkF6x4rY9f6OKcCXTFEM37Bu_xvVxrkyAfkZ0XGvJYQv6glrbJWkV7Qfl3H7dWmjO57wWWLn7_Hr9imx-T-y9VuPAKKkK_c2L-yzd8zj1dYf1hmzKnOwK46mIDZ86Q28udNz-pHjcj3RxTjd4f1u4YKh4a66A8EJRTDC4iJ6wjutbggl3Aywb1RNksp1HlmEl2ifHm51Jw4guPEUSo2KnZajN8qBqUBmLMq1rcHOIM6IMsvFsrto-ZESwvgKJobcGIVFystPbEljA0pEbtK2UZTVWCi0Q"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the jwk endpoint from auth0

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "use": "sig",
            "n": "nGXHKrVaXqj1jOgZ37FD4BIVYlhvL-CGflccHEczP7vtYfArkNOVjW4V4DY1zQNHd9da5WKdVuuEzjsAC_E74u7u6zTJVhLC4reYCPqClkK-fxLRlRSeGTRbEjXxk4hJZ2bdEnzfM_RK8mcxLgSDF4jar45atWHvebsaI8LdzxnaOLqA2aQbKQbhPnGnngdR6kdZTWSBq-Kkmh73r4hZ0Nm9cKgA7q9v06Uq1XGiEqgDlCn3_dSDaUaZKJvrDSOMtftv71O15mDrC8bJLufF_oROOTrSqk-9LMBnjO5vUSK4A4i-JjR4hQnAZvryVW6RyqUiEkaU6lWR_miwAqZytw",
            "e": "AQAB",
            "kid": "MMBwle23wTQWIvx-CW55l",
            "x5t": "OmYvzIheoHg5Ik2y2c7iXbxxpwU",
            "x5c": [
                "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"
            ],
            "alg": "RS256"
        },
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "use": "sig",
            "n": "yad3J942bXm02rmBBQ5zuekX7j7cxUugPCnfJukUxQurzpkmxAcfCaXhzzwNjqlRdzd8BVyTwzGfBxdBKJCcor-_6a_D2B8p9B_5-3aCIzrf0zWer9gs_K1E-FXynHnGxXtx3RuddsQXyc423bIFKbq3TJcpVZrubMQPAkJfnIxaVx9_iB4obZYxUW70Gd8dUHcChExBgZZWipy0Tn5FIQUpNxT2_oR7PGqWG2DQW3f08Om21dQha-RiCVMSSQ_8nXjEsYR6r7R8EjCQhukv7B-PsX4vgpjVo8tOCzvfuTeLlwWTP07zGUw0ZTTWm4_v1GTIoYY-5YqU7iuu_AjAOw",
            "e": "AQAB",
            "kid": "hmQrSAlxu9ngNAlLkPeqY",
            "x5t": "gUenOFsCzw4z9VJVIrjuqI4T_UM",
            "x5c": [
                "MIIDDTCCAfWgAwIBAgIJbHLvlGpDKY0SMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMCQxIjAgBgNVBAMTGWRldi03d2EwaHptcC51cy5hdXRoMC5jb20wHhcNMjIwMjA4MjI0NzE3WhcNMzUxMDE4MjI0NzE3WjAkMSIwIAYDVQQDExlkZXYtN3dhMGh6bXAudXMuYXV0aDAuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyad3J942bXm02rmBBQ5zuekX7j7cxUugPCnfJukUxQurzpkmxAcfCaXhzzwNjqlRdzd8BVyTwzGfBxdBKJCcor+/6a/D2B8p9B/5+3aCIzrf0zWer9gs/K1E+FXynHnGxXtx3RuddsQXyc423bIFKbq3TJcpVZrubMQPAkJfnIxaVx9/iB4obZYxUW70Gd8dUHcChExBgZZWipy0Tn5FIQUpNxT2/oR7PGqWG2DQW3f08Om21dQha+RiCVMSSQ/8nXjEsYR6r7R8EjCQhukv7B+PsX4vgpjVo8tOCzvfuTeLlwWTP07zGUw0ZTTWm4/v1GTIoYY+5YqU7iuu/AjAOwIDAQABo0IwQDAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBRSZQM0uQyFnmwU3W+DYUc7z4nQyjAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAoQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAF3Psiqk32Dq10WEtT5T2UIxczim6pKGv+edH5yPxDLlfJjnFNK7PMMQS7whyYrMzMZoJv4VUlNvQ3hkg1ICvYzwGDM4kNgRP7TTOQqgomCslpUnqsLNjVwBJBqC0XpMcmldcUXbYaXwUN73PiEkjFDNjjezQnJlO7o3CFySDqaahKevHXoTbex5RjwnrjziC/pVyjlruaEFZUhrAsi+jTQ8NUkPWj2APtU3WhMAYGAvccd9CXl3CSQXRUVtd8yTV7z8YNdG3MAx/JSrpB/m2ghrRUhML7Jn8io4HY0iP4fbQ46FAjLAdWDDDf+IupqEysOegdnuok6dY61qv750C4A="
            ],
            "alg": "RS256"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `fail the signature validation`? Seems unlikely that auth0 is generating token that fail signature validation.

Comment: Yes.  I have added the access token, which shows an invalid signature.

Comment: "I am able to login correctly, but the access and id tokens that is generated always fail the signature validation"

where and how you get validation error? how you try this ? can you describe a little bit more ..

Comment: If you want to try angular and Auth0 you should probably use the auth0 quickstart that is given to you when you create an SPA on auth0. Spring would come into that as an resource server or API that would be accessed with an access token when the user needs infomation from an API. What you mention as a tutorial really isn't a howto for angular running from a java server assuming that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264578/spring-authorization-server-and-openid-connect-and-angular-oauth2-oidc

Comment: @Imranmadbar seethe access token posted and paste into a jwt validator like jwt.io.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I was trying to use an agnostic way of authenticating the user if there is a need to change to another idp for authentication. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't pass in an `audience` parameter to the `authorize` endpoint, Auth0 will return an opaque access token rather than a JWT. You can configure Spring Security pass in an audience parameter as follows:

```java
package com.example.apigateway;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${okta.oauth2.audience}")
    private String audience;

    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    public SecurityConfiguration(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .authorizationEndpoint(authorization -> authorization
                    .authorizationRequestResolver(
                        authorizationRequestResolver(this.clientRegistrationRepository)
                    )
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    private OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                clientRegistrationRepository, "/oauth2/authorization");
        authorizationRequestResolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(
            authorizationRequestCustomizer());

        return authorizationRequestResolver;
    }

    private Consumer<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.Builder> authorizationRequestCustomizer() {
        return customizer -> customizer
            .additionalParameters(params -> params.put("audience", audience));
    }
}
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/issues/596) if you need a WebFlux version.

Comment: I am trying this solution, but running into an issue on the login now.  The error I am getting is [access_denied] Service not found:.  What audience do you recommend?

Comment: If you haven't created a custom audience, `https://<your-auth0-domain>/api/v2/` should work.

Comment: As an update, I use the name of an existing api in auth0 as the audience.  That appeared to have worked.  One thing I have noticed is the kid is matches the jwk of http://localhost:9000 which is the same as the issuer.  However JWT decoders such as jwt.io still shows the signature as a failure which is strange.  Could that be because I am using PCKE?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For signature validation, you need to provide: **public key** and **private key** from you IDP server in **RSASHA256 (  .. )** input section